# Testing htaccess for 500 server error without actual error

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, 500-error

After reading some tutorials, I have created an error file, that should be displayed instead of 500 server error. I have added it to domain's root and added the following line to the bottom of .htaccess:

```
ErrorDocument 500 /error.html
```

Now the question is, how can I test it on a live site and make sure that the error page appears, when site really crashes?

Any suggestions are much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I created a folder called `http500` in the www root

I put a `.htaccess` file into that folder with the following:

```
Redirect 500 /http500
```

I then opened it
http://example.com/http500

You can try out different error pages

```
Redirect 501 /http500
```

or

```
Redirect 502 /http500
```

or

```
Redirect 503 /http500
```

It did not require any server restart, the change applied immediately.

Sources:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/8687536/534883
https://bibwild.wordpress.com/2013/06/05/how-to-make-apache-fake-a-500-http-response/

Comment: "I created a folder ..." - You don't need to actually create the folder, if you are testing the main `.htaccess` in the root. eg. `Redirect 503 /http503`.

Answer (score 1):

> make sure that the error page appears, when site really crashes?

It depends what you mean by "when the site really crashes". A "500 Internal Server Error" is such a generic error... if the server is unable to process the request for whatever reason and there is no other suitable response then it defaults to a 500 error response.

The "problem" here is that for the majority of *uncontrolled* 500 errors, defining the 500 ErrorDocument *late* in `.htaccess` is simply too late to have any effect.

You can trap more 500 error responses if the 500 ErrorDocument is defined earlier in the server config or `<VirtualHost>` container - this is where it should be defined. But even then, depending on the severity of the error, the custom ErrorDocument may still not be called.

You can "artificially" trigger a 500 response as @TimoHuovinen suggests and this would trigger your custom 500 ErrorDocument, however, whether this triggers when your "site really crashes" is another matter entirely.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but I was currently facing the same problem, so I thought I'd share my (simple) solution without creating subfolders

Since

```
Redirect Err# /path
```

leads me to unstartable server, I found a better solution for me.

If you use custom error documents like:

```
ErrorDocument 400 /res/err/400.php
ErrorDocument 401 /res/err/401.php
ErrorDocument 403 /res/err/403.php
ErrorDocument 404 /res/err/404.php
ErrorDocument 500 /res/err/500.php
```

You can simply add the following to your .htaccess (or your VirtualHost or Server config)

```
RewriteEngine on

# To test our custom error pages
RewriteRule ^/err400(.*)$ https://your.servername.dev/res/err [NC,R=400,L]
RewriteRule ^/err401(.*)$ https://your.servername.dev/res/err [NC,R=401,L]
RewriteRule ^/err403(.*)$ https://your.servername.dev/res/err [NC,R=403,L]
RewriteRule ^/err404(.*)$ https://your.servername.dev/res/err [NC,R=404,L]
RewriteRule ^/err500(.*)$ https://your.servername.dev/res/err [NC,R=500,L]
```

Now you can test your error pages by typing the url in your browser, like that:

```
http://your.server.dev/err400
```

or:

```
https://your.servername.dev/err403
```

Hope that helps B)

Addendum:

Ensure mod_rewrite is enabled

Answer (score 0):

Create a new directory end enter a non functional .htaccess (e.gg, with a Syntax Error or similar) file in that directory. Then access that dir with a browser.

Comment: Sorry, I did not understand it. Should I create a new category in the root of  the domain and then create .htaccess in there ( what is 'non functional'? )?

Comment: This won't trigger a custom 500 ErrorDocument that is itself defined in `.htaccess`.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this:

> How to trigger 500 Internal Server Error in PHP?

https://stackoverflow.com/a/8687536/534883

Comment: Triggering a 500 error response in PHP won't result in an Apache defined 500 ErrorDocument being called. In the same way a 404 response from PHP won't trigger the 404 Apache response.